# Duda con SQLite al subir actualizacion a play store

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

subi hace poco una app al play store la cual utiliza varias tablas de sqlite, las demas actualizaciones que subi no necesite modificar las que ya estaban solo agrege algunas nuevas, ahora agrege una columna a una de las tablas y tengo la duda de como hacer para que los usuarios no pierdan los datos que ya guardaron.... probe de subir la app al play store a prueba interna y al abrir los fragment que trabajan con esa tabla, claramente me da error.... mi clase sql es la siguiente

````
public class SQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQL(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase basededatos) {
    basededatos.execSQL("create table articulos (cantidad real, codigo text, descripcion text , precio text)");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table BaseDescargada (codigo text, descripcion text , codigo1 text, descripcion1 text,codigo2 text, descripcion2 text ,codigo3 text, " +
            "descripcion3 text ,codigo4 text, descripcion4 text,codigo5 text, descripcion5 text ,codigo6 text, descripcion6 text ,codigo7 text, descripcion7 text ," +
            "codigo8 text, descripcion8 text ,codigo9 text, descripcion9 text ,codigo10 text, descripcion10 text ,codigo11 text, descripcion11 text )");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table carrito (cantidad text, descripcion text, preciomuestra text, precio float, id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table ventas (id text, cantidad text, descripcion text, precio text, fechamuestra text, fecha real)");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table mysql (descripcion text, precio text, fecha real)");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table clientes (cliente text, cantidad text, descripcion text, precio text, fechamuestra text, fecha real, id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");
    basededatos.execSQL("create table actualizar (codigo text, descripcion text unique, precio text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE articulos ADD COLUMN cantidad");

        }
    }
}```



Mi duda es tambien si la columna nueva se llena con valores 
vacios o nulos en los productos ya almacenados... Muchas gracias!

---

Hola jorge gracias por tu respuesta. el problema es que subo la actualizacion a prueba interna en play store y la app crashea al intentar hacer la consulta y no se porque si no deberia causar problema
De esta manera genero la consulta 

  SQL basededatos = new SQL(getContext(), "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase editorbd = basededatos.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = editorbd.rawQuery("select cantidad, codigo, descripcion, precio from articulos order by descripcion  ASC",null);
````

Answer (score 2):

Cuando subes una actualizacion a la tienda esta debe ser configurada en el `build.gradle` con un `versionCode` superior, esto provoca que se llame el metodo `onUpgrade()`, aqui es donde se define la actualizacion o alteracion de las tablas.

En tu caso simplemente no realices ninguna operacion en este metodo y los datos se conservaran cuando tu aplicacion se actualice.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
       

    }
}
```

---

Al revisar la actualizacion de tu pregunta, es incorrecto declares la version de la base de datos como 1:

```
SQL basededatos = new SQL(getContext(), "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase editorbd = basededatos.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = editorbd.rawQuery("select cantidad, codigo, descripcion, precio from articulos order by descripcion  ASC",null);
```

Es muy importante que realices la creacion de tu base de datos y su administracion en base a la documentacion oficial:

[**Cómo guardar datos con SQLite**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite?hl=es-419)